# Parskip before parts in exam?

Tags: spacing, enumerate, exam

I would like to add some space between the end of a paragraph and the beginning of `parts`. By default, this spacing is quite weird in comparison with *traditional* LaTeX.

Here below you see that `(a) Foo` doesn't have much space below the question text. I would rather have the same as what I get from lists (2nd red arrow).

Where should I adjust this parameter? Adding a `\vskip 1em` each time isn't clean enough.

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}    
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\qformat{%
  \Large\textbf{\thequestiontitle}
  \quad \thepoints \hfill
  \vrule depth 1.5em width 0pt
}

\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
\setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
\setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\titledquestion{1\hspace{0.7em} Foo}[10]\par
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\par
\begin{parts}
    \part Foo
\end{parts}
\end{questions}

\section{List}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\par 
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Foo
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

I see that I can change the `topsep` value in the `exam.cls`:

```
 \list{\partlabel}%
    {%
    \usecounter{partno}\def\makelabel##1{\hss\llap{##1}}%
    \settowidth{\leftmargin}{(m)\hskip\labelsep}%
    \labelwidth\leftmargin\advance\labelwidth-\labelsep
    \topsep=1em     % <<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \partopsep=0pt
    \partshook
    }%
  }% newenvironment{parts}
```

But since it is hardcoded, I don't know how can I change it without monkey patching the exam class. I've tried this but it doesn't really work:

```
\xpatchcmd*\process@part{\topsep=0em}{\topsep=1em}{}{}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `parthook`

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{exam}    
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\qformat{%
    \Large\textbf{\thequestiontitle}
    \quad \thepoints \hfill
    \vrule depth 1.5em width 0pt
}

\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
}

\renewcommand{\partshook}{% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \setlength{\partopsep}{5ex}%
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{questions}
        \titledquestion{1\hspace{0.7em} Foo}[10]\par
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\par
        \begin{parts}
            \part Foo
        \end{parts}
    \end{questions}
    
    \section{List}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\par 
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Foo
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```